# If $x$ and $y$ are rational and $z$ is irrational $(x-y)z + z -1$ is irrational where $x > y + 3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If $x$ and $y$ are rational and $z$ is irrational $[(x-y)z + z -1]$ is irrational where $x > y + 3$.

So the first step I would do is:

$$(x-y)z + z -1 = zx - zy + z -1 = z(x-y+1) -1$$

and since $x-y > 3$,
then $x - y + 1 > 0$ and is rational
$z(p/q) -1$     (where $p/q$ is a rational number).
Since $z$ is irrational and $p/q$ is not $0$, then $z(p/q)$ is irrational
and finally irrational $- 1 =$ irrational.

Comment: The reasoning is correct.

Comment: That's correct.  What is your question?